# Question about boundedness of a sequence in $ W^{3,q} $ for any $ 1\leq q < \frac{N}{N-1} $

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I have asked this question several months ago, I have understood every thing and there are good comments and they have helped me , but only I have a question about tomas comment, how can Calderón-Zygmund estimate prove that $\{u_n \}$ is bounded in $ W^{3,q} $.

**And I have another new question, can some one says that why $v$ , $u$ are a positive solutions and why we can consider $u_n >0$ and $u_n \in L^{\infty}$ .**

**I have not changed the question, and it was :**

Can someone see the **10th** line of page **9** [in this article](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.uam.es%2Fpersonal_pdi%2Fciencias%2Fmapperez%2Fultimos_trabajos%2FPerezPrimoRevised.pdf&ei=78m7VPjuFsP5UtKegnA&usg=AFQjCNEWUiwjrczoQQhswakkxluVyOuXHQ&sig2=8W3V033ABeiUkr3cxtf2Qw&bvm=bv.83829542,d.d24) and give a hint that why $$ \nabla v_n \to \nabla v \   \ (a.e.)$$ and $$ v_n \to v $$ and how with theorem 2.1 we could conclude there exists $ u \in W^{2,q}(\Omega) $ such that $ v=-\Delta u $

Thanks

Comment: I don't see quickly why $\nabla v_n\to \nabla v$ a.e. now but $v_n\to v$ because the compact embedding, i.e., $W^{1,p}\subset\subset L^p$ for any $p$, and hence the strong convergence follows.

Comment: Is the boundary still Lipschitz? Then, the $W^{2,q}$-regularity of $u$ can be inferred from regularity theory ($v\in L^q$). However, $v$ is even better than $L^q$. Maybe this helps without boundary regularity. I'm also not sure aboout the pointwise convergence, potentially, the equation plays a role there.

Comment: You can use Calderón-Zygmund estimates to prove that $\|u_n\|_{3,q}$ is bounded, which implies the a.e. convergence of $\nabla v_n$, however, it is worth to note that the a priori estimate $\|v_n\|_{1,q}\le C\|f_n\|_1$ is true, so you can avoid all this problem and conclude directly that $v_n\to v$ strongly. Take a look [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00032-011-0168-1#page-1) and references therein.

Comment: @Denoising: Isn't the authors' assertion that (perhaps up to a subsequence) $v_{n}\rightarrow v$ strongly in $W_{0}^{1,q}$ for $1\leq q<N/N-1$? So why does strong convergence follow from your observation?

Comment: @Tomás Could you please elaborate on why the the boundedness of $\left\|u_{n}\right\|_{3,q}$ would imply the a.e. convergence of $\nabla v_{n}$, as opposed to the weaker assertion of a.e. convergence of a subsequence of $\nabla v_{n}$?